# C# console for an auctioning system, getting an error code and really not sure why

Tags: c#

I am programming an auctioning system in C# on visual studio 2010, i have 7 classes:
auction
system
bid
buyer
seller
item
user,

on my user class i am trying to program my username and password but get an error message, below is my code.

```
public abstract class user
{
    protected string username;
    protected string password;

    public user(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.**password** = password;
    }
    public string getusername()
    {
        return username;
    }
    public string password()
    {
        return **password**;
    }
}
```

the errors are in bold (double ** next to the words)

I am extremely novice at C# please help if possible. I am doing tutorials etc so no need to post them just in a predicament where I need this sorting.

Comment: You should've shown the error message you got as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a string field called `password` and a method that returns a string called `password`. The compiler doesn't know which you mean.

Try renaming your method to `getpassword`:

```
public string getpassword()
{
    return password;
}
```

There are different ways of coding this - but this should get you started.

**NOTE** as C# is case sensitive the usual convention is to start methods with upper case and use Pascal Case for compound names. So your methods would become:

```
public string GetUsername()
{
    return username;
}

public string GetPassword()
{
    return password;
}
```

had you done this originally then you wouldn't have had a problem as `Password` for the method name would have been different to `password` for the field name.

See [this page on .NET naming conventions](http://www.akadia.com/services/naming_conventions.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks mate, really appreciate it, dont know why i didnt think of this before haha.

Comment: @meNo - don't worry - I've been programming for 30 years and *still* miss the obvious from time to time.

Comment: 30 years is amazing. cant wait till i am able to help others, im doing a coursework at the minute making this console its the first experience ive ever had, really enjoying it and learning lots just finding it really difficult. im dreading programming the system class

Comment: Please learn to use the correct upper/lower casing from the start. See my code.

Comment: @Erno - **I** know the correct casing. As this is a homework type question I was just pointing the OP in the right direction. I'll add a note.

Comment: You would usually use properties for this though

Comment: @meNoProgramgood - The code compiles but there is a general consensus on how properties, fields, classes and methods should be named and cased (upper and lower case). Please compare the code above to the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have methods and fields with the same name. Either go with properties or rename your methods. Example code coming up...

```
public abstract class User
{
    protected string _username;
    protected string _password;

    public user(string username, string password)
    {
        this._username = username;
        this._password = password;
    }

    public string GetUsername()
    {
        return _username;
    }

    public string GetPassword()
    {
        return _password;
    }
}
```

or

```
public abstract class User
{
    protected string _username;
    protected string _password;

    public user(string username, string password)
    {
        this._username = username;
        this._password = password;
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get 
        {
            return _username;
        }

        set
        {
             _username = value;
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the = value mean? or do?

Comment: A set(ter) of a property has a special keyword named `value` it contains the value assigned to the property. So when you write code like this: var me = new User("Erno", "123"); me.Password = "456"; The setter will be called and value will be "456" and will be assigned to _password.

Answer (score 0):

Your error on "password" occurs because "password" is a method and not a property.

try this:

```
public class User {
  public User (string name, string password) {
    this.Username = username;
    this.Password = password;
  }
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```